# Checkbox unclickable inside <li> html entry - breaks in conjunction with javascript used to collapse/expand list items

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-lists

I found some code used to collapse and expand my list items nicely, as I didn't want the entire list showing immediately when the page showed:

```
$(function(){

 $('li:has(ul)').click(function(event){

      if(this==event.target){

       $(this).css('list-style-image',(!$(this).children().is(':hidden'))?'url(plus.gif)':'url(minus.gif)');

       $(this).children().toggle('fast');

      }

       return false;

     })

     .css({cursor:'pointer','list-style-image':'url(plus.gif)'}).children().hide();

     $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({cursor:'default','list-style-image':'none'});

});

</script>
```

I added some list items with text boxes, but now I also need checkboxes. When I add checkbox within the list item, it becomes unclickable.

I've narrowed it down to the above code screwing up the checkbox. Is there something I can modify with the code so that it allows the checkbox to be checked?

Comment: Any chance of a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: + oned for the link.  I had heard Fiddle mentionned in other SO posts but first time I checked today. 

 Love at first sight buddy. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Alright... first time using JS fiddle, but I made up a quick demo. Hopefully this helps! http://jsfiddle.net/GZJ4K/   In the demo, click where it says "Click here to expand" and for me the checkbox is uncheckable.

Comment: Just as an aside, what's the intent behind the `if(this==event.target)`?

Comment: Not totally sure - I pulled this from a tutorial on collapsible lists that was less than informative about the reasoning behind each line of code. It worked well for a while, up until I needed to add a checkbox.

Comment: @David @Rolio I believe that's a check to avoid triggering the animation when elements inside the `<li>` are clicked - only if the `<li>` itself was clicked should that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `return false` which in a jQuery event handler is equivalent to `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. Comment that out and it works.

Here's the [edited, working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZJ4K/2/).

Comment: Nice, worked perfectly! That's about the only part I didn't comment out earlier when I was trying to narrow out what was causing the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Done! First time using stackoverflow, and JS Fiddle. Been programming for several years, so it's always great to learn something new. Thanks :)